# How is a http signature header generated?

Tags: http, cryptography, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to talk to a non-public API. They use a Signature header to encode their requests. I found the private key RSA on my device, and through trial and error managed to find out which of the headers are used to compose the signature. (Basically editing the headers in mitmproxy and seeing or the API responded with "Invalid signature".

However, now I have hit a wall, since I have no idea how the headers and content together are signed to create the signature. Is there any convention in this?

What I tried:
Add the headers together with a ., append the content and sign
Add the headers without a ., append the content and sign
Add the headers with a ., base 64 encode them, then add the base64encoded payload and sign
Add the headers without a ., base64 encode them with payload

All the time i am getting the invalid signature error. Anything else I can try?

```
Raw:
{}

Headers:
X-Triodos-RequestId: 37169686-6D43-458F-904C-661D094F0853
X-Triodos-Device: 3474EAE1-FD11-4EF3-BFE5-BB5DE9679B99
X-Triodos-Administration: TBNL
X-Triodos-DeviceType: UGhvbmU6fjpBcHBsZTp+OmlQaG9uZSA3On46aU9TOn46MTMuMzp+OjEzLjM6fjplbi1OTDp+Ok5MOn46NjY3On46Mzc1On46Mi4wOn46TWYrRmxFTW0xM2NxWWhha2NIQ3p4V1EwMWIzc3M3azB1cVIzME9jPQ==
X-Triodos-ClientVersion: 3.35.0
X-Triodos-SessionToken: 61bpPboz8kE_ydX7YvR4gD81RKob0Y_mIg7IjCxUU43m3MreoC_SjehALX56B3iHJKiwQA==
```

The signature is composed with the raw payload:

```
X-Triodos-SignatureSourceType: raw-v2
```

Comment: Did you search for something like `triodos api signature`? If you did, you probably found [this](https://developer.triodos.com/docs/signatures), but as this is the first time I'm hearing about Triodos, it might not be helpful. Or it might describe how to create the signature.

Comment: Unfortunatly, that is the public API, which I cannot use. The functions I want are in the private API.